# .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|files|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

The website is hosted on the latest version of **XAMPP locally**. When I load the website with the `.htaccess` file in place, it won't load at all. I get a `server error`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Checked log file, here's an error that might help point the issue out. Does this mean that mod_rewrite has not been included?

```
.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or 
defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Because some people don't think questions about esoteric programming languages (such as Brainf*ck, Befunge, mod_rewrite and Malbolge) are programming related.

Comment: mod_rewrite is hardly an esoteric language

Comment: @K Prime: It's Turing complete (allows you to construct conditionals and loops), is difficult to code in, and extremely difficult to debug. It ticks all the boxes! And it's got regex support!

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Please change "on" to "On", as I have suggested...

Comment: Well, K Prime's right. It doesn't appear to be programming related: `The Esoteric is a hardcore/rock band founded in 1996 from Lawrence, Kansas.`

Comment: I did change it to On, still get the same error in the log and still won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first line to

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Also, replace your RewriteRule with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If this doesn't help, *check your log file*. Server errors will normally issue something to the log file.

If that doesn't help, you'd best crank up your RewriteLog and post some of that here.

Answer (score 1):

The first line, as has been pointed out, should be changed :

```
RewriteEngine On
```

but you really ought to redirect requests only if they do not already exists (otherwise all your static requests, eg images and css, would go through index.php as well)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure to enable mod_rewrite in XAMPP? A quick googling revealed that (at least in older versions of XAMPP), mod_rewrite was not enabled by default. Maybe this is your issue?